# A question on elementary logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose, for the sake of discussion, that I am given that the following implication is true:
$$q<n \implies \bigg(q<n \iff \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \iff \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q\bigg).$$
Assume further that $\sigma(q)/q < \sigma(n)/n$ holds.

Here is my question:

> Does it follow (by [Exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic))) that the implication
>   $$\sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n$$
>   holds?

It is known that
$$q<n \implies \bigg(q<n \iff \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \iff \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q\bigg)$$
is logically equivalent to
$$q<n \implies \bigg(q<n \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg).$$

I guess it all boils down as to whether
$$q<n \implies \bigg(q<n \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg)$$
can be simplified to
$$\sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \bigg(\sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg),$$
by using the assumption $\sigma(q)/q < \sigma(n)/n$ and [Exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)).

**MY ATTEMPT**

By Exportation, we get that
$$q<n \implies \bigg(q<n \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg)$$
is logically equivalent to
$$\bigg(q<n \land q<n\bigg) \implies \bigg(\sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg)$$
This simplifies to
$$q<n \implies \bigg(\sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg)$$
which in turn is logically equivalent to
$$\bigg(q<n \land \sigma(q)<\sigma(n)\bigg) \implies \bigg(\sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg),$$
again by Exportation.
Simplifying, we obtain
$$\sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \bigg(\sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg).$$
This is logically equivalent to
$$\bigg(\sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \land \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q\bigg) \implies \bigg(\sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg),$$
still by using Exportation.
This simplifies to
$$\sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \bigg(\sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg).$$
Now, together with the unconditional result $\sigma(q)/q < \sigma(n)/n$, the hypothesis $\sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q$ simplifies to $\sigma(q)<\sigma(n)$.  Consequently, we have
$$\sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies \bigg(\sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n\bigg).$$
One final application of Exportation then yields the desired result.

> > **IS THIS PROOF CORRECT?**

Comment: Are you aware that $a \iff b \iff c$ isn't the same thing as $(a \iff b) \land (b \iff c)$ ?

Comment: @DanielV, thank you for your comment.  Yes, I am aware of that.  Perhaps I was not too accurate with my question.  I meant to have the biconditional
$$q<n \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q \implies \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \implies q<n$$
to follow from the hypothesis $q<n$.

Comment: @DanielV, isn't that biconditional (in spelled-out implication form) the same as $$q<n \iff \sigma(q)<\sigma(n) \iff \sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q?$$

Comment: Are you aware that $a \implies b \implies c \implies d$ is not the same as $(a \implies b) \land (b \implies c) \land (c \implies d)$, but it is actually the same as $(a \land b \land c) \implies d$ ?

Comment: Not too familiar with it, but it seems the rule you are trying to invoke is $(a \iff b) \land (b \iff c) \land (c \iff d)$ is equal to $(a \implies b) \land (b \implies c) \land (c \implies d) \land (d \implies a)$.

Comment: Also, unless the actual definitions of $\sigma$, $q$, $<$, etc are relevant to the proof, you could clean the whole thing up by replacing $q < n$ with $A$, $\sigma(q) < \sigma(n)$ with $B$, and $\sigma(q)/n < \sigma(n)/q$ with $C$.  Basically, if $\sigma$ is relevant, then define it, if it isn't relevant, then leave it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof cannot be correct, because the result does not follow.

For a counterexample, take $q=\sigma(q) = n =1$, and $\sigma(n)=2$. Then $q<n$ is false, and so the whole implication is automatically true. It is also true that $\sigma(q)/q < \sigma(n)/n$. But it is not true that $\sigma(q) < \sigma(n) \rightarrow q < n$.

Of course, this only tells us *that* your proof is not correct, and not *what* is wrong with your proof.

One thing wrong  with your proof is that $P \leftrightarrow Q \leftrightarrow R$ is not equivalent to $P \rightarrow Q \rightarrow R \rightarrow Q \rightarrow P$: First of all, the conditional is not associative, so you need  parentheses to indicate what that second statement even means, but going by the rest of your proof, you must mean $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow (R \rightarrow (Q\rightarrow P)))$. But that is a tautology, and  hence not equivalent to $P \leftrightarrow Q \leftrightarrow R$, which clearly is not a tautology.